# How to remove all symbols after dot

Tags: bash

For example I have IP addresses list

```
192.168.20.5
192.168.20.12
192.168.20.141
```

How to remove all symbols after **last** dot and get this list (below) at the output

```
192.168.20.
192.168.20.
192.168.20.
```

I tried this:

```
LAN=$(nslookup localhost | awk '{print $2}' | head -1)
hosts=$(echo "${LAN::-1}"{1..254} | xargs -n1 -P0 ping -c 1 | grep "bytes from" | awk '{print $4}')
```

But `::-1` not suitable, because the number of digits may vary

Comment: On SO we do encourage users to add their efforts which they have put in order to solve their own problems, please do add your efforts and let us know then.

Comment: If you are using Awk anyway, use it to its full potential. Replace `grep "bytes from" | awk '{print $4}'` with `awk '/bytes from/ { a=$4; gsub(/[.][^.]*$/, ".", a); print a}'`; see also [useless use of `grep`.](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep)

Comment: Similarly, `awk '{print $2}' | head -1` can be replaced with `awk '{ print $2; exit }'`

Comment: With **GNU** awk: `awk '{NF--} NF++' FS="." OFS="."`